# How to create a class instance directly with a call to a class method?

Tags: python

I'm facing a problem that I can't solve. Is it possible to make *pipe* be an instance of the class *MyClass* concerning the call to the class method *do_something*? And make *print(isinstance(pipe, MyClass))* return True.  This means that on the call *pipe* goes through the class method *do_something* and then reads the constructor `__init__`.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attr = 42
        print("Attribute initialized to", self.my_attr)
        
    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        print("Doing something...")


pipe = MyClass.do_something()
print(isinstance(pipe, MyClass)) # True
```

Comment: This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @flakes I was trying to analyze how a library code that uses this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a class instance directly with a call to a class method by returning an instance of the class within the class method. In this case, you can modify the `do_something` method to create an instance of `MyClass` and return it. The code for it is as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attr = 42
        print("Attribute initialized to", self.my_attr)
        
    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        print("Doing something...")
        return cls()  # Create an instance of MyClass and return it


pipe = MyClass.do_something()
print(isinstance(pipe, MyClass))  # True
```

Now, when you call `MyClass.do_something()`, it will create an instance of `MyClass` and return it. As a result, `pipe` becomes an instance of `MyClass`, and `isinstance(pipe, MyClass)` returns `True`.

Output:

```
Doing something...
Attribute initialized to 42
True
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an instance of MyClass and call the `do_something` method on it you can modify the code like this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attr = 42
        print("Attribute initialized to", self.my_attr)
        
    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        obj = cls()
        print("Doing something...")
        return obj

pipe = MyClass.do_something()
print(isinstance(pipe, MyClass)) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the walrus operator:

```
(pipe:=MyClass()).do_something()
print(isinstance(pipe, MyClass))
```